# HTTP DELETE with parameters

Tags: http, post

Is it against the HTTP Protocol and Best practice to have parameters in a HTTP DELETE (verb) - specifying what should be DELETED.

For example:
VERB: DELETE

```
http://localhost:9393/delete-dns-record?zone=codedtrue.com&type=A&hostname=blog3&attributes=xyz
```

(using the url parameters to delete the correct resource)

If so, how should this be implemented?

Comment: Using the URI, like any request? What parameters are you talking about? Do you mean a body? Then see [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request).

Comment: The body is clearly not a good idea given some non-supported implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is sufficiently dealt with in the link found in the comment by CodeCaster.

Should we encoded identity of the resource in the message body of a DELETE, the best answer is NO. The RFC does not say NO, but it does clearly say this may or may not be supported.